# Why can't answer-blocked user answer their OWN question?

Tags: support

So I understand my posting rep isn't good at all, but why can't you answer your OWN question. Stack Overflow said I was answer-blocked because my posts on OTHER users' questions and my questions didn't get a good rating. But why can't you answer your OWN question if you actually DO know the answer?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe it has something to do with being **answer-blocked**?

Comment: Earn some reputation before trying to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rate-limiting and blocking works like this. The system looks at how the user's previous posts were received by the community and imposes a rate limit or a block on the user. The idea is that if someone has repeatedly posted bad contents to the site, they are likely to continue in the future unless they learn what the standards of the site are. **The aim is to reduce harm to the site, as a whole**, because bad posts need cleaning up by the rest of us.

What you are suggesting would make some limited sense if the aim of rate-limiting and post bans were to project question askers from bad answers. After all, it should be your own business if you wish to answer your own question with a bad answer (which, again, is what the system *estimates you are likely to do*, if your past history is one of bad answers). However, as I've pointed out above, the aim is to protect the site, not individual question askers. This is why answering your own question is not exempted from rate limits or bans. **A bad answer to your own question does not require less cleaning up than a bad answer to someone else's question.**

Answer (score 6):

Because a bad answer is a bad answer. The fact it's your question is irrelevant; the system doesn't differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I can explain it is this:  your privilege for writing answers was revoked until you can demonstrate that you can clean up your existing answers and make them viable for the site.

That privilege is universal; it doesn't matter if it's your question.

If I were you, I'd clean up what answers aren't deleted and let the community gain a bit more trust in your answering.